# Is there any command line tool for purchasing anything online?

Tags: command-line, application, unix-philosophy

I continue to pursue ways to do everything from the command line and while it does not seem common whatsoever I am curious if there is one single example of a command line tool that allowed someone to purchase something over the internet, make a payment, and expect the delivery of said good. Not using a terminal browser on a website or something, but an actual command line application.

Thank you.

Comment: I "purchase" software with `apt-get install`. Payment 0, instant delivery. :D

Comment: Text-based web browser - `links` - is the answer to the question. May be tricky to order sth but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such commands exist in troves. I mean, computers are used for a lot of commerce!

The things you can buy, from the top of my head, using non-interactive commands, would include

- compute resources
- storage capacities
- stocks, and generally any exchange-traded securities
- cryptographic currencies
- electronic components
- train tickets
- software subscriptions
- anything on the larger retailer catalogues
- telephone numbers, contracts, prepaid volume
- and much more

Generally, anything that looks like it could make money through offering an automatable way of buying their stuff, Or a way of letting third parties resell their stuff, has a commercial interest in offering some kind of interface (an *API*) for programs to make such a purchase online.

And either a specific client exists, or just any http client (most usually `curl`) can do that.

I'm intentionally not listing services, because we're not a product recommendation service, and such actions would just attract spam and off-topic conversation.

You now know that you just need to look for the API that the seller you're interested in might offer, and figure out whether they offer a specific client or just give you an HTTP API (REST is the buzzword there) for you to peruse using e.g. curl.

Note that legal requirements on most larger economies (the European Union, Japan, USA at least as far as I know) require you to have interactively authenticated yourself to set up your account and payment method, to avoid automated computer fraud and automated money laundering.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I guess I won't ask for specific recommendations then. Although I do know of many cloud computing services that have APIs (AWS, etc.), I have honestly never seen a lot of the other tools you are mentioning, I am afraid. You said they are often when people need automation. So I should google for like, B2B wholesale sellers for whatever I want to buy, since they are most likely to offer an API? I just discovered Sharetribe which does fit the bill, though. Thank you.